# Some of the gradle dependency needs to be declared twice to be available for the microservice. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have build.gradle in a common project which is been shared by other microservices and each microservice has its own build.gradle also.
There is one dependency as 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
This is added in build.gradle of common project(Project A) and is been consumed by other project(Project B). The issue is the service throws error and we need to add the same dependency ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security') in build.gradle of Project B also.
Do someone know the reason behind it ?

Comment: You should share a snippet how you build.gradle files look like, how you sdd the dependency.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
}

Comment: @criztovyl the idea is that same line of dependency
`dependencies { implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1' implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' }`
need to be added in the Project A and Project B which is consuming Project A for the list of dependencies, in order to run the service smoothly.  Actual behaviour should be Project A build.gradle should be the only place where the spring-boot-starter-secuirty needs to be added.